# Derivative Naturalization for Spouse and Children (Germany) for Non EU Citizens

Tags: germany, citizenship, family

I am a non EU citizen and would like to apply for citizenship for me and my family in Germany. Do the requirements like B1 language level for naturalization also apply to your spouse and children? If the main applicant can apply citizenship in 6 years due to being able to speak the language fluently (C1 Level), does that mean the spouse and children can apply in 6 years as well together with the main applicant, even without the same language level (not even B1)?

I read this on the government website:

Section 10, para. 2 of the Nationality Act
Spouses who are not yet eligible for naturalization and minor children may apply for naturalization along with their eligible spouse or parent, which gives families of foreigners the possibility of acquiring German citizenship together.

[https://www.bmi.bund.de/SharedDocs/faqs/EN/topics/migration/staatsang/Erwerb_der_deutschen_Staatsbuergerschaft_durch_Eingbuergerung_en.html?fbclid=IwAR0U2S4uxJ_W5tJ3Y8TEXWMz3a79Y5xspavINiT_qO0lPZ5VbeaGwhhUEC0#:~:text=What%20is%20derivative%20naturalization%3F,-Section%2010%2C%20para&text=Spouses%20who%20are%20not%20yet,of%20acquiring%20German%20citizenship%20together](https://www.bmi.bund.de/SharedDocs/faqs/EN/topics/migration/staatsang/Erwerb_der_deutschen_Staatsbuergerschaft_durch_Eingbuergerung_en.html?fbclid=IwAR0U2S4uxJ_W5tJ3Y8TEXWMz3a79Y5xspavINiT_qO0lPZ5VbeaGwhhUEC0#:%7E:text=What%20is%20derivative%20naturalization%3F,-Section%2010%2C%20para&text=Spouses%20who%20are%20not%20yet,of%20acquiring%20German%20citizenship%20together)

Comment: You should add the next line to your question:  *Apart from the minimum residence requirement, the requirements for derivative naturalization are the same as for naturalization on the basis of legal entitlement.* Since language skills equivalent to level B 1 are generally required, the answer to your question should be clear: no, it cannot be even less than B1.

Comment: @MarkJohnson unless the child is younger than 16 years: https://germanlawarchive.iuscomp.org/?p=266

Answer (score 2):

The reason your family members are eligible for citizenship may be your status, but citizenship is granted to individuals, not families.

As such, *each individual* must fulfil all conditions.

The site you linked even says so:

> Apart from the minimum residence requirement, the requirements for derivative naturalization are the same as for naturalization on the basis of legal entitlement.

So yes, every single individual that wants to become a citizen needs B1 level or better. Exception are minors below 16 years, who only need "age appropriate language skills". Obviously, a 5 year old child in kindergarden cannot get a B1 certificate, not even German children would be that fluent. But they do need to have a grasp of the German language in line with that of other kids.

Comment: Unless that individual is under 16, in which case the requirement is somewhat vague: https://germanlawarchive.iuscomp.org/?p=266

Comment: @phoog You are right, thanks for the link.